# How to find css classes (in e.g. chrome dev tools) that use a specific font-family?

Tags: css, fonts, google-chrome-devtools, webflow

I'm currently in the process of updating all my websites from using webfonts to hosting the fonts locally by myself. This process is a little bit frustrating, because I often can't find the css classes of the webfonts. At the moment, it's more a "try and error" kind of thing, where I'm just klicking trough the google chrome dev tools and looking for the corresponding css classes. So I was wondering if there is a simple way to look in a published website via browser for the css classes of a specific font family? (I cannot search for the classes in the IDE, because in this use case the websites where developed with webflow)

EDIT: The websites in question were created with a "building block" system called "Webflow". There, the fonts are selected via graphical interfaces. Now the problem is that somewhere in these old and huge web pages there are CSS classes that use the "Lato webfont". I want to replace this font, but I can't search for used fonts in this graphical interface. What I can search for are the CSS classes. So my idea was to use the Chrome Dev Tools to find out which CSS classes used the Lato font to ultimately replace it.

Comment: DevTools>Network | refresh your page.  Filter the view to show only CSS. Search these files for `url` references that pull in webfonts.

Comment: @fnostro Thanks for the message! With that explanation I was able to find the entry of the request that loads the font from the google api. But what I can't find are the css classes that are using this font, this is what I'm looking for -  Do you know by any chance how to find this?

Comment: It's going to be very time consuming due to css cascade.  Inspect an element that is using that font. In devtools on the right switch to "Computed" styles tab.  select "font-family" and open the tree - it should show you where it's being defined for that element.  Hopefully there are not that many instances.  But if each page sets it's own font...well...I'm glad it's not me :) (sorry)  Managing old code is a nightmare, but pays well

Answer (score 0):

#### Find css rules by properties

If you can't edit you site's css files globally you might at least get some sort of "cheat sheet" containing all selectors matching certain property values.

```js
let cssRules = getCssRules();
let filterLato400 = findRulesByProperties(cssRules, {
  "font-family": "Lato",
});
console.log(filterLato400);

let filterLato400Italic = findRulesByProperties(cssRules, {
  "font-family": "Lato",
  "font-weight": 400,
  "font-style": "italic"
});
console.log(filterLato400Italic);

//get all css rules in document
function getCssRules() {
  let cssText = "";
  let rules = [
    ...(document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules)
  ];
  let cssArr = [];

  rules.forEach(function(rule) {
    let selector = rule.selectorText;
    let cssText = rule.cssText;
    if (selector && cssText) {
      let properties = cssText
        .replace(selector, "")
        .replace(/[{}]/g, "")
        .split(";")
        .map((val) => {
          return val.trim();
        })
        .filter(Boolean)
        .map((vals) => {
          return vals.split(":");
        });
      cssArr.push({
        selector: selector,
        properties: properties
      });
    }
  });

  return cssArr;
}

//filter css rules by properties
function findRulesByProperties(css, filters) {
  let classList = [];

  css.forEach(function(rule) {
    let selector = rule.selector;
    let props = rule.properties;
    let vals = [];
    let valsFilter = [];

    for (let key in filters) {
      let filterName = key;
      let filterValue = filters[key];
      valsFilter.push(filterValue.toString());
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
      let prop = props[i];
      let propName = prop[0];
      let propValue = prop[1].trim();
      if (valsFilter.indexOf(propValue) != -1) {
        vals.push(propValue);
      }
    }
    if (vals.length == valsFilter.length) {
      classList.push(selector)
    }
  });
  return `results ${classList.length}:   ${classList.join(", ")}  ||  match: ${JSON.stringify(filters)}`;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Georgia;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 700;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 400;
}

.classLato400 {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 400;
}

.classLato400italic {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
}

.classLato700 {
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-weight: 700;
}

.classRoboto400 {
  font-family: "Roboto";
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

In the above example we're searching for all rules containing `font-family:Lato` (and other filters like font-weight or font-style).
You could paste your main css file in the snippet to get a list of selectors matching all criteria.

#### Replace external @font-face rules

If I got you right and your ultimate goal is to replace externally hosted font files with local ones (e.g. to improve GDPR compliance), you don't need to get every css font-family class reference.

The most important part are the `@font-face` rules that are actually responsive for downloading font files.
OK that's not perfectly correct since a font file won't be downloaded unless some DOM element uses this particular font-family.
In other words, your css might actually contain a plethora of unused font-families – on the other hand if they aren't used anywhere they won't be downloaded (so browsers have a default lazyloading method for fonts).

#### Example: you need to replace google webfonts with locally hosted fonts

- Open your devTools and switch to the "Font" tab
- Now you can see a list of all downloaded font files as well as their origin (URL) and their "Initiator" – the source file, that initiated the file download. Usually this would be a `<link>` stylesheet reference or an `@import` rule within your css, but it can also be a javaScript font loader method.

[image: Dev tools font tab]

By inspecting the "URL" column, we can clearly see if a font is loaded from an external host.
Clicking the "Initiator" row/entry will open the file triggering the download – this will either be a file (like a .css) you want to completely remove or just a portion of a css file (take a closer look at @font-face rules, especially the `src` properties).

**Following the google webfonts use case/example**
(actually pretty similar to other font delivery services)

- obviously we need to get local copies of my previously externally hosted font files –
  [google web font helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) might be helpful to get a ready-to-go `@font-face` css and a download package including all needed font files.
- we need to delete all css files or `@font-face` or `@import` rules that are still referring to external file sources and replace them with custom local font file urls.

**Possible shortcuts to remove external font file references:**
Check your HTML/template head for undesired elements like these
(so containing an external URL like "fonts.googleapis.com"):

- `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700" rel="stylesheet">`
- or within inline `<style>` tags for `@import` rules like `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700')`
- or similar `@import` rules within your main css file – they should usually be found at the top of your css code.

Delete these references and replace with  custom `@font-face` rules like so (example is based on google web font helper output using "Roboto" font-family and font-weights 400+700 ... regular and bold).

```
/* roboto-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('fonts/roboto-v30-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
/* roboto-700 - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url('fonts/roboto-v30-latin-700.woff2') format('woff2'); 
}
```

**Inspect the network tab once again**
If everthing is working fine we should see the locally retrieved font files for each style (e.g. regular, bold, italic, bold italic etc.)
If not: **double check your file paths!**
Seriously, this is probably the most common source of errors. (e.g "../fonts/" or "./fonts/" or just "fonts/").

Comment: Thanks for the detailed message! That's also a great explanation, just unfortunately not quite appropriate for my use case. I should have possibly described it in a bit more detail in my post. So I updated my post and if you know an answer to that, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @sarius: I've added an example containing a js helper method. This way you can get some sort of "cheat sheet" containing all selectors using the Lato.